# Show single category Axis For Amchart Multi Panel Horizon Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I'm trying to show category axis for Amcharts Multi Panel Horizon chart. I tried setting the category axis property to true, but it enabled the x axis for all the charts.

```
 "showCategoryAxis": true,
```

Is there a work around to show Multi horizon chart with a single x axis.
Here is [demo](https://codepen.io/jay-raj/pen/mqwKXe) with `"showCategoryAxis": true,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the buildPanel function so that `showCategoryAxis` is set to false by default for all panels and then set one of them (presumably the last one) at the end of the init handler loop to false. You'll also want to set [`axisHeight`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#axisHeight) to 0 in `categoryAxesSettings` so that the height of the last panel, or whichever one has the category axis enabled, doesn't shrink.

```
function buildPanel( dim ) {
  return {
    // ...
    "showCategoryAxis": false,
    // ...
  };
}

//in addInitHandler:
  for ( var i = 0; i < dimensions.length; i++ ) {
    // ...
  }

  chartPanels[chartPanels.length - 1].showCategoryAxis = true;

  chart.panels = chartPanels;
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/6cf299b3915bd933eaba5ea5c6101df8/)